# How to prevent MessageBox on Exception in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, exception, try-catch, messagebox

I'm trying to make a C# (Windows Forms) application which utilizes SQLite. Anyway, my code is this :

```
try
{
    db.Insert("COLUMN_NAME", data);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    //MessageBox.Show(e.Message);    
}
```

I made `COLUMN_NAME` unique, so it throws an SQL error, intentionally. But I don't want to see the error message in a `MessageBox`, so I commented out the `MessageBox.Show()` line, but still the error message pops up. Is it a property of try / catch ? If so, how can I prevent it ?

### P.S.

I know there are better ways to do this task, but it is not important. I just want to learn how to get rid of error messages in exceptions.

Thanks for any help !

Comment: Does it pop up in Visual Studio, or as an actual message box?

Comment: Are u sure the popup is MessageBox?

Comment: have u correctly, cleaned and rebuilded solution

Comment: That's interesting... are you sure there is no more code that you're not showing us?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it looks exactly like a MessageBox. And no, this is the exact same code, except COLUMN_NAME. And yes, I cleaned, recompiled, still the same. And OK, Thanks for help. Apparently there is something wrong, which I wanted to learn. And apparently there are downvoters around, so I'm just closing the question and trying to solve it myself. Thanks again !

Comment: Are you running your code from the exe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured the problem. The line `db.Insert();` itself has a try/catch block, which shows a MessageBox.

I found the code [here](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/157830-using-sqlite-with-c#/#/) by the way.

Thanks again for all the help !

Answer (score 0):

There is RunTime error in your line at

```
db.Insert("COLUMN_NAME", data);
```

So you need to fix this.

Comment: I forgot to state the library I'm using. It is now linked in my answer. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Try by clean and then build your code. Then run the code. Sometimes dll file is not refreshed. It will be regeneratedby clean and build your code.